# How do I show shading for test renderings

Tags: rendering

Sample frame:
[image]

Until EEVEE gets into an official version, I'm trying different settings to test a character animation I made in cycles. Just good enough to see the character and floor shadows. No need for it to be super sharp it's just a test. I need the floor to see how the feet land. Her eyes have no lens so there is no transparencies to worry about.

1920x1080 resize @ 50% if lower difficult to see any details.

Multiple importance off.

There is only the floor and the character with a gray background as a light source.

Renders = 7 samples.

GPU rendering with my GTX1060 3GB
Tiles are maxed for GPU performance @480X270 = exactly 4 tiles per frame.
I got 0.99 frames per second.

CPU i7 2600K
Tiles are maxed for CPU performance @48X27 = exactly 40 tiles per frame.
I got 0.94 frames per second.

What else could I check or uncheck to speed that up even more?

Comment: Why even bother with Cycles? If your goal is to capture shadow under feet you can do that with Viewport AO. It's pretty much the same effect as in here with this grey sky light. Then you can do OpenGL preview render in speeds you won't even have chance to come close to with Cycles..

Comment: @Jerryno I need to see the feet connect to the floor but OpenGL doesn't show shadows. I can't tell if her feet are floating above till it gets rendered to see how it turns out. There will be more occasion where I need cycles view as the test.

Comment: Did you try turning on ambient occlusion for the viewport?

Comment: @MicroMachine It does make everything look ugly but that solved my footing problem. I didn't know Blender had that for the viewport. Thanks!

Comment: If it looks ugly you can definitely improve that if you need. Follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jb_Xf4SWljs (Blender Render - not Cycles) and you can achieve as nice results as in EEVEE.

Comment: @Jerryno It is more for testing purposes, it does what it needs to do. But I'll watch it, anything I can learn about Blender is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ambient Occlusion** can be enabled for the **Viewport**, which can help visualize distances between objects, you can even turn it up if you need:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I changed the question to fit the answer better, I hope that is acceptable to do.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I'd love to see your animation when it's finished :)

Comment: Still trying to figure out the Dope Sheet - Action - NLA that is all that is left for me to figure out then I'm good to go.